# Typo3 Scheduler: "The APC backend cannot be used because apc is disabled on CLI"

Tags: typo3, scheduler

I created a typo3 Command for the scheduler and when I execute it manually it works fine. But when its executed automatically (via cronjob), there is the following error:

```
The APC backend cannot be used because apc is disabled on CLI
```

I googled this but the results are not helpful, does anyone know what exactly this means?

Comment: It means that TYPO3 uses APC for caching, but the APC module (a PHP Opcode-Cache) is deactivated when PHP is called using the command line ("on CLI"). Solution: Either do not use APC at all, or activate it for the command line interface as well. Here is how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245242/php-apc-in-cli-mode

Comment: You could also switch to another Opcode-Caching mechanism, e.g. the mechanism built into PHP from version 5.5 on (or 5.4? Not sure).

Comment: my problem is, I don't know if I'm using "APC" or not - which feature of typo3 / extbase uses APC?

Comment: I'm not sure TYPO3 itself uses APC (could be as a cache) - it's a PHP-thing, that speeds PHP up by preventing it from compiling all the source files for each request and instead saving the compiled sources (Opcodes) in memory. This does not work on the command line, because command line processes die after they have finished executing, freeing all their memory and thus loosing the saved Opcodes. Because of this, it is sensible to deactivate APC on the command line.

Comment: but then how do I solve my problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TYPO3 CMS` uses the APC Cache backend for the `extbase` object and reflection caches.

If you do not want to use the APC cache backend, then you can do so in the `Install Tool` in the menu point `Configuration Presets`. There is one where you can choose between `Database cache backend` and `APC cache backend`. The APC cache is chosen automatically during installation if it is available.

You can also change your server configuration and make the `APC cache backend` available from CLI. http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.enable-cli
Please note that the CLI cache is no persisted across requests, therefore there is no gain from doing this.

You can read more about the `Caching Framework` in the `TYPO3 CMS Documentation`: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/CachingFramework/Index.html

Comment: And you can't tell the Scheduler to use `Database Cache backend` while the rest of the site uses the `APC cache backend`?